# how to make a div automatically scroll to bottom without javascript

Tags: html, css, scroll

is there a trick to do this(cause i want my div to automatically scroll without javascript)

Comment: There is no way to scroll a page without javascript.

Comment: this question is far to broad, what div, and what do you mean automatically scroll to bottom? What code do you already use?

Answer (score 0):

If you want do this without javascript you can make your div tag and hidden that. Then you can show your content when user scroll the page. Also you can use AOS library. Please see this link https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URL fragment:

`example.com/example#divtoscrollto`

`<div> <div>{scrollable content}</div> <div id="divtoscrollto"></div> </div`

Place an element at the bottom of the scroll content then if you change the url to that fragment for it's id it will jump to its location.